# Postgresql: What is the best way to search in arrays of strings with a subarray

Tags: arrays, postgresql, search

I have an array of 49 strings for each row in my table.

How can I efficiently search for the row through the database with the subset of strings, contained by the row's array.

### Update

**Example**

Let's say I have a row in my database with the following array:

```
data
{"None", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4", "24", "108", ..., "18425675268"}
```

And I want to find this row with the array:

`{"None", "0", "0", "0", "0", "18425675268"}`

Comment: It's hard to tell without more details, but most probably you are looking for the `&&`  or `@>` operator: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name! That's exactly what I needed. I've added example to the question, to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name, I realized that I needed to query in the way:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE array_column @> subarray;
```